# Matlab plot of a function with 2 variables

Tags: matlab

I have a problem to plot a function with 2 variables: 
if i do:

```
x= linspace(0,5);
y=linspace(0,5);
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=log(x.*sqrt(y-x));
mesh(x,y,z);
```

I get this error:
**Error using mesh (line 76) X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex.**

I think because I have some complex results in the computation.
How could I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of output do you expect? It's possible to plot the absolute value using `mesh(x,y,abs(z));`, but I'm not sure if this is what you want. `quiver` is another possibility to plot your data.

Comment: i need de plot of the function that i wrote

Comment: another way could be: if i have complex number in z, put out... so remain just positive number and negative. i need the plot of this function

Comment: @GiovanniFar: Think about what you are trying to do. You have 4D-Data, there is no possibility to simply plot 4D-Data. For 2D-Data Points on a 2D-Grid, the already mentioned `quiver`-plot is a nice option.

Comment: i have f(x, y)=log(x*sqrt(y-x)) if i want to see the plot in matlab of this function what i have to do ? i want to see this function in a 3d graph. because i need to see x,y and z

Comment: i know what do you mean, but in geogebra i can so i think it's possibile also in matlab... i don't know what exactly do geogebra but i can see in a correct way the plot... maybe there is like waterfall command in matlab where it ignore the complex number.

Comment: @GiovanniFar: If this is possible in geogebra, please create such a plot and upload it. I'll try to reproduce it in matlab. It is possible, but you have to do some kind of projection.

Comment: This plot does not contain any of the data points with an imaginary part. They are simply left out. You can reproduce this in MATLAB using `z(imag(z)>0)=nan`

Comment: ok but i dont understand where i have to insert 'z(imag(z)>0)=nan'

Comment: fantastic, it works, before i meaned this... how can i put out the complex number because this number are not in the R^2 domain of the function

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting complex results is the sqrt(y-x) part in your code. y is less than x at almost half of the points of your grid which leads to computing the square root of a negative number.

So, as Daniel suggested, you can use abs(z). Alternatively you could check if it is OK for the particular application to compute sqrt(abs(y-x)) to make sure you have a positive number under the square root